# Condition for angular select option in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular project, I have a select element with an option. for option, I used ng-repeat for looping purposes. so in the option, I have four different options. and I have four different boxes. if I select any option based on that those boxes will hide and show.
how to do this? anyone please help me to fix this.

This is my HTML code:

```
<select select2 id="environment" name="environment"
              ng-model='filter.environment' data-live-search="true"
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in authorizationtype" value="{{key}}"
                ng-bind="value"></option>
      </select>
```

HTML box codes:

```
<div class="boxone"></div>
<div class="boxtwo"></div>
<div class="boxthree"></div>
<div class="boxfour"></div>
```

This is my js code:

```
AUTHORIZATION_TYPES = {
  1 : "None",
  2 : "Basic",
  3 : "Bearer",
};
```

Comment: use `ng-if` based on `filter.environment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if directives, to achieve that.

```
<div class="boxone"></div>
<div ng-show="filter.environment == 1" class="boxtwo"></div>
<div ng-show="filter.environment == 2" class="boxthree"></div>
<div ng-show="filter.environment == 3" class="boxfour"></div>
```

ng-if removes html element whereas ng-show/ng-hide just hides them, you will have to choose one according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you much, it's perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) which can render elements selectively.

The variable `filter.environment` will be changed as the user select options. It will hold the `key` of your object. So, in the markup :

```
<div ng-if="filter.environment === 1" class="boxone"></div>
```

Comment: I added but it doesn't change. all the boxes are visible. not changing based on the option click.

Comment: The question is about AngularJS but your answer is for Angular.

Comment: Edited. The only difference however is the *

Comment: It's `ng-if`, not `ngIf` and the correct link to the docs is [THIS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). It's the ngIf directive, but the HTML attribute is ng-if.

Comment: Edited. the answer for NG1